# Is Outbox Pattern necessary in sycnchronous API call

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, microservices

Suppose I have an API endpoint which calls directly to this service.

```
class MockService {
   private final SomeRepository someRepository;
   private final MessageBroker messageBroker;

   @Transactional(rollbackFor = { SomeRelatedException.class })
   public void sendReq() {
      Data data = new Data();

      someRepository.save(data);

      messageBroker.publish(new Message(data));
   }
}
```

I wonder if **outbox pattern** is still necessary here because in case of message broker failure Spring will automatically rollback the transaction so the data will never save to the db and the user will get the response code like 50x error and so on.

Comment: What happens if your app happens to crash (think power cycle) between `someRepository.save` and `messageBroker.publish`?

Comment: I did try simulate that situation using System.exit(1) and put it in between. it turns out that the data was not save to the db I'm not sure if Spring handles this for me or it's just db transaction.

Comment: `System.exit` won't simulate a crash (as shutdown hooks will still be executed).